# Reading file inside driver Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

Is it possible to read a file in distributed cache inside a Hadoop driver?
I have implemented the Tool Inteface and I am using the -files to add the file to the distributed cache.

Or this file will be copied to distributed cache after I start my job?

Answer (score 0):

I open the hadoop code. The files will be copied to distributed cache after the job submission. So in the driver the file not exists in the distributed cache.